# I am trying to connect to Amazon Web Services Instance and use my jupyter notebook. I am stuck at trying to open jupyter notebook on my local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to follow the instructions given in:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/deep-learning-jupyter-aws#gs.jFBj7tM

I followed the steps till "Connecting to Jupyter in the Browser"

After that I tried to open https://15.216.176.173:8888 on google chrome on my laptop, but, it was of no use.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And you can ssh into your cloud machine? Then it's probably the security settings that prevent you from connecting to that machine on port 8888

Comment: Open the port 8888 in your ec2's security group . 
if you can share the screenshot of browser when you are hitting url , that's would be helpful